# Run task after 10 seconds, unless user presses button

Tags: java, android, timer, scheduled-tasks

In my Android app, I want to schedule a task to run in 10 seconds, unless the user presses a specific button.
What is the best way to do this? Should I use a `java.util.Timer`, `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` or something else?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A handler is fit for this if you are accessing the UI from your task :

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run () {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
```

in your button action :

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Otherwise, a `Timer` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

and `Handler` and its `postDelayed` method

```
private Runnable requester = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
                 // cpde to execute here             
    }
};

public void onClick(View v) {

 new Handler().postDelayed(requester, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You able to use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and Handler.